# `web.py` sessions with Apache2

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, web.py

## Question:

I am in the process of porting my `web.py` app from its built in server to Apache2 using `mod_wsgi`.  All is well and the code executes, except for the sessions.

Firstly, note that the sessions work fine with the old server.  I am testing as follows: I render a page called `layout` which has the lines

```
$session
${'loggedIn' in session}
```

Due to the fact that `session` (which is a `web.sessions.Session`) is initialised with `initializer={'loggedIn' : False}`, I expect the second line to always render as "True".  This it does with the default server.

However, on Apache2 with mod_wsgi, it is not the case.  If I restart apache, then it renders as True, but subsequent refreshes of the page render as False.

I understand that sometimes the `cookie_path` can be the culprit, but have set that to `/`, and am unsure of what else could be the problem.

### Code:

#### `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp/webUtils.py/
AddType text/html .py
<Directory /var/www/myapp>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

#### `/var/www/myapp/webUtils.py`

```
import sys,os
abspath = os.path.dirname(__file__) or '.'
sys.path.append(abspath)
os.chdir(abspath)

import web
(...)

## The configuration for the sessions (this function just reads in 
## the file and turns it into a dictionary).
session_configuration = config.getConfiguration('config/sessions.cfg')

for i in session_configuration:
  web.config.session_parameters[i] = session_configuration[i]

web.config.debug = False

app = web.application(urls,globals(),autoreload=False)

session = web.session.Session(app, 
                              web.session.DiskStore('/home/robert/sessions'),
                              initializer={'loggedIn' : False})

render = web.template.render('templates',
                             globals={'session':session},
                             base='layout')

# Get the WSGI stuff
application = app.wsgifunc()
```

#### `config/sessions.cfg`

```
timeout : 60*10
secret_key : "stuff"
cookie_name : "someName"
cookie_path : "/"
```

## EDIT: Update

By running exhaustive tests, I have found that calling `webUtils.session._load()` as the first line in a `GET` fixes the whole problem.  I thus postulate that the `_processor` of that `Session` is not being called (even though it is in `app.processors`).  Why not is still a mystery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem.  It had to do with the multi processes, but ended up being that the `Session` object that created a hook (and thus got loaded every time) was not the same as the object that my page code was seeing.  Thus if I `load`ed and `saved` my session in each `GET` statement and removed the hook, it all worked.

To solve this, I just needed to undo an assumption I made and reinstate the code

```
if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), {'count': 0})
    web.config._session = session
else:
    session = web.config._session
```

which I had removed, since it is only given for the builtin server in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a multi process configuration and so cannot rely on an I'm memory session cache as subsequent requests can go to different processes. Also, since using embedded mode of mod_wsgi, Apache can decide to shutdown your processes if it thinks they are no longer needed.

You need to make sure you are using a database for the session cache.

Alternative using mod_wsgi daemon mode with the default of a single process.

Comment: When you say "cache" you mean the `DiskStore`?  Surely that is process ignorant?

Comment: Sorry, was looking at just the configuration which I didn't see anything disk related in, and not too much at the code. Is interesting that it isn't working then, but then you have been the second person I have seen lately who has been unable to get disk based sessions working with mod_wsgi. Is your directory /home/robert actually readable/writable to the Apache user your code is running as. Usually home directories wouldn't be readable, let alone a file in it being writable. The other person having issues gave up on web.py and used Flask, which is probably a better choice these days.

Comment: Changing the file to one `www-data` may access changes not much.  Now the file is created (yay) and contains correct pickled data, but it is not translated into the `session` object.